# Proof for the greedy algorithm

Tags: algorithm, greedy, proof

I recently tried solving a problem on Codeforces I did get the solution right but am now trying to prove it. The algorithm is something like this:

Take the smallest discount and apply it on the most expensive ones and take the two consecutive less expensive ones for free. Then do it continuously till no items are left.

I am kind of stuck on the proof. It would be great if someone can give me a formal proof by contradiction.

[Problem](http://codeforces.com/contest/262/problem/C)!

Answer (score 1):

It goes in two parts:

**Which discount to pick?**

Suppose we choose to take any other discount (2 free for `m` items) than the smallest one (`n` items, `n<m`): Buying articles `a(1)` to `a(m)` we get articles `b` and `c` for free. We could just take the smallest discount, buying articles `a(1)` to `a(n)` to get `b` and `c` for free, and the buy the items `a(n+1)` to `a(m)` for the full price to end up in the same situation. Therefore picking the smallest discount is at worst on par with other choices.

**Which free articles to pick?**

Now suppose we apply the discount to items `a1` and `a2` instead of the most expensive ones `b1` an `b2` (`cost(a1)<cost(b1)` or `cost(a2)<cost(b2)`). Let's assume that `cost(a1)<cost(a2)` since the cases are symmetrical. Three cases arise:

1. Somehow we still manage to get `a2` for free as part of a promotion: then we could also have gotten `a1` if we hadn't picked it already.
2. We have to pay for it, as part of a discount. The discount allows us to buy items costing  up to `c`. One of the following arises:

   - `c<=cost(a1)`: we may swap `a1` and `a2`, which leads to a lower cost for this basket, without changing anything else.
   - `cost(a2)<=c<cost(a1)`: let's call `d` and `e` the items we get out of this second discount, `d` being the most expensive one. We could have picked `a2` as a free item in the first discount, replacing it by `d` in the second and picking `a1` as a free item in the second discount, resulting in a lower or equal cost.
3. We buy it out of a discount: we could have picked `a2` and paid `a1` for a lower cost without changing anything else, hence picking `a1` was suboptimal.

Comment: In the which discount to pick ? part you have proved that if we pick b and c only the algorithm will give the same answer but what if we choose other items as in the algo i am not choosing b and c?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I did not make any assumptions in picking `b` and `c` except the fact that we can pick them. The point is that anything we can do when we pick the discount using many articles, we can do *at least* as well with the discount using fewer articles.